# Copying a string into a new array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to read a string in an array, and if a character is not any of the excluded characters `int a = ('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'y'||'w'||'h');` it should copy the character into a new array, then print it.

The code reads as:

```
void letter_remover (char b[])

{

int i;
char c[MAX];
int a = ('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'y'||'w'||'h');
for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (b[i] != a)
    {
        c[i] = b[i];
    }
    i++;
}
c[i] = '\0';

printf("New string without forbidden characters: %s\n", c);
}
```

However it only prints `New string without forbidden characters: h`, if the inputted array is, for example `hello`. I'd like the output of this to be `ll` (with h, e and o removed).

Comment: You need to research what the `||` operator does.

Comment: Well currently your statement evaluates to `int a = 1;`. Have a look for "C logical or" to understand the `||` operator

Comment: `||` is the **logical** OR, `|` the **bitwise**. `||` is short-circuit, BTW.

Comment: Also you are incrementing `i` twice in your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (b[i] != 'a' && b[i] != 'e' && b[i] != 'i' && b[i] != 'o' && b[i] != 'u' && b[i] != 'y' && b[i] != 'w' && b[i] != 'h')
```

The boolean OR operator just returns `0` or `1`, it doesn't create an object that automatically tests against all the parameters to the operator.

You could also use the `strchr()` function to search for a character in a string.

```
char a[] = "aeiouywh";

for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (!strchr(a, b[i]))
    {
        c[i] = b[i];
    }
    i++;
}
c[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: So if (!strchr(a, b[i])) means: if not any of the chars in array a, return a pointer to b[i]) ?

Comment: `strchr(string, char)` returns a pointer to the first match for `char` in `string`. If it can't find it, it returns `NULL`, which is false, and `!` inverts the truthe value. So `!strchar(a, b[i])` means "can't find `b[i]` in `a`".

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = ('a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'y'||'w'||'h');
```

...has an entirely different meaning than you expect.  When you Boolean-OR together all those characters, `a` becomes 1.  Since b[] contains no character value 1, no characters will be excluded.  Also, your c[] is going to have empty slots if you had tested correctly.

You can use strcspn() to test if your string contains your forbidden characters.  For example...

```
// snip
int i=0, j=0;
char * a = "aeiouywh";
while (b[i])
{
    int idx = strcspn(&b[i], a);
    if (idx >= 0)
    {
        if (idx > 0)
            strncpy(&c[j], &b[i], idx);
        j += idx;
        i += idx + 1;
    }
}
// etc...
```

Also, you must be sure c[] is large enough to contain all the characters that might be copied.

Comment: If I use a switch statement from a different function instead of the ||'s, how can I make sure there are no empty slots in the new array?

Comment: you need an index variable for both b[] and c[], they must be incremented independently, only increment c's index variable when assigning to c[index].